# F# using set to filter map keys to get a reduced map

Tags: filter, f#, set, maps, key

i have a problem regarding F# and using maps and sets to filter a map with keys. 
I have tried a couple of methods but i cant wrap my head around how it works in F# and need some advice on how to code what i want in F#.

This is the code i have tried so far and only returns the first instance where the set head = key:

```
let rec sumECTS cs cb = 
Map.filter(fun key desc -> key = (cs |> Seq.head)) cb
;;
```

Where cs = courseset:

```
let courseSet = set [ cn1 ; cn3 ; cn6 ];;
```

and cn# is a courseNo of 5 digits.

Cb = courseBase:

```
let Coursebase1 = 
Map.empty.
    Add(cn1,cd1).
    Add(cn2,cd2).
    Add(cn3,cd3).
    Add(cn4,cd4).
    Add(cn5,cd5).
    Add(cn6,cd6);;
```

Where cd# is ECTS point of 2 digits.

Comment: Very unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: I guess you try to do it - `let sumECTS cs = Map.filter (fun key _ -> Set.contains key cs) `

Comment: @FoggyFinder You should make that a proper answer. It's the most obvious answer, and makes sense given the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something along these lines (example results in 66)? https://dotnetfiddle.net/n2gdar

```
open System

let sumEcts courseSet courseBase =
    let isPartOfCourseSet cn _ =
        courseSet |> Set.contains cn

    courseBase
    |> Map.filter isPartOfCourseSet
    |> Map.toSeq
    |> Seq.map (fun(cn, cd)->cd)
    |> Seq.sum

let courseBase =
    [
        (11111, 11)
        (22222, 22)
        (33333, 33)
        (44444, 44)
        (55555, 55)
    ]
    |> Map.ofList

let courseSet =
    [11111; 22222; 33333 ]
    |> Set.ofList

courseBase 
|> sumEcts courseSet
|> Console.WriteLine
```